# How can I count unique comma-separated values in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to build a formula to walk a column of comma-separated values and count the number of *unique values* seen.  I am using Excel 2010.  I have a screenshot of some example data...

[image: Screen shot of data]

The output of the formula in this case should be 5.  In other words, the formula must count the following values: 2.3.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4

I have figured out how I can simply count the raw number of comma-separated values like this...

> **=SUMPRODUCT(--(M123:M127<>""),LEN(M123:M127)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M123:M127,",",""))+1)**

However, that formula yields `7`, because it counts 2.4.3 and 2.4.4 twice.

I'm at a loss for how to reject repeated comma-separated values in different cells of the same column.

Due to the other systems that must interface with the spreadsheet, answers can only use a formula; they must not use VBA or some kind of filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add some intermediate formulas to your sheet, here's a possible solution.

Based on the ranges in your example:

Put in cell `N123` This returns the part to the left of `,` or the whole cell if no `,`

```
=IFERROR(LEFT($M123,FIND(",",$M123)-1),M123)
```

Put in cell `O123` This returns the part to the right of `,` or `-` if no `,`

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID($M123,FIND(",",$M123)+1,999)),"-")
```

Put in cell `P123` This returns `1` if cell `N123` is unique in the list, plus `1` if cell `O123` is unique

```
=AND(ROW()+1=ROW($N$123:$N$127)+MATCH($N123,$N$123:$N$127,0),$N123<>"-")
+AND(ROW()=IFERROR(MATCH($O123,$N$123:$N$127,0),""),$O123<>"-")
+AND(ISNA(MATCH($N123,$N$123:$N$127,0)),ROW()+1=IFERROR(ROW($N$123:$N$127) 
    +MATCH($N123,$O$123:$O$127,0),FALSE),$N123<>"-")
+AND(ISNA(MATCH($O123,$N$123:$N$127,0)),ROW()+1=ROW($N$123:$N$127)
    +MATCH($O123,$O$123:$O$127,0),O123<>"-")
```

Copy cells `N123..P123` down to `N123..P127`

The number of unique items is `=SUM(P123:Q127)`

This assumes there are at most 2 items in each data cell.  If this is not the case you will need to add more intermediate columns, and extend the formula in `O123` accordingly.  If there are many more than 2, this will quickly get out of hand.

FWIW, you say a VBA solution is not posible, but is a VBA **user defined function** ok?

It would look something like `=CountUnique(M123:M127)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using VBA functions. Paste the following into a module.

```vb
Function ListCount(list As String, delimiter As String) As Long
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Split(list, delimiter)
ListCount = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
End Function

Function RemoveDuplicates(list As String, delimiter As String) As String
Dim arrSplit As Variant, i As Long, tmpDict As New Dictionary, tmpOutput As String
arrSplit = Split(list, delimiter)
For i = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
    If Not tmpDict.Exists(arrSplit(i)) Then
        tmpDict.Add arrSplit(i), arrSplit(i)
        tmpOutput = tmpOutput & arrSplit(i) & delimiter
    End If
Next i
If tmpOutput <> "" Then tmpOutput = Left(tmpOutput, Len(tmpOutput) - Len(delimiter))
RemoveDuplicates = tmpOutput
'housekeeping
Set tmpDict = New Dictionary
End Function
```

Then in your worksheet, you can use the following formula:

```
=ListCount(RemoveDuplicates(A1,", "),", ")
```

where `A1` is your comma-separated list.

*NOTE: You will have to add the* `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` *reference to your VBA project (under* `Tools` > `References...` *in the VBA Project Editor window).*

Comment: If you don't mind, you could [convert early binding to late binding](http://superuser.com/a/615472/50173). This way he and all other users don't have to add the reference. Early binding usually leads to a lot of confusion. In my own firm too: "Hey, your script is not working. Come here and fix it asap!"

Comment: @nixda True. I just pulled the RemoveDuplicates function from another project of mine, so I didn't write the code with other users in mind. Feel free to make the change yourself if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Chris Neilsen's input, I am going to try to modify our systems and use this... Source: [Mr Excel Forums - Post dated 1 Jan, 2010 at 10:04am](http://excel.bigresource.com/Track/excel-D80D5Ub1/)

```
Function UNIQUECOUNTIF(ByRef SR As Range, _
                        ByRef RR As Range, _
                        Optional ByVal Crit As Variant, _
                        Optional NCOUNT As Boolean = False, _
                        Optional POSTCODE As Boolean = False) As Long
Dim K1, K2, i As Long, c As Long, x, n As Long
K1 = SR: K2 = RR
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(K1, 1)
        If Not IsMissing(Crit) Then
            If LCase$(K1(i, 1)) = LCase$(Crit) Then
                If POSTCODE Then
                    x = Split(Replace(LCase$(K2(i, 1)), ",", " "), " ")
                Else
                    x = Split(LCase$(K2(i, 1)), ",")
                End If
                For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                    If POSTCODE Then
                        If IsNumeric(x(c)) Then
                            If Not .exists(x(c)) Then
                                .Add x(c), 1
                            ElseIf NCOUNT Then
                                .Item(x(c)) = .Item(x(c)) + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                        If Not .exists(x(c)) Then
                            .Add x(c), 1
                        ElseIf NCOUNT Then
                            .Item(x(c)) = .Item(x(c)) + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Else
            If POSTCODE Then
                x = Split(Replace(LCase$(K2(i, 1)), ",", " "), " ")
            Else
                x = Split(LCase$(K2(i, 1)), ",")
            End If
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                If POSTCODE Then
                    If IsNumeric(x(c)) Then
                        If Not .exists(x(c)) Then
                            .Add x(c), 1
                        ElseIf NCOUNT Then
                            .Item(x(c)) = .Item(x(c)) + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not .exists(x(c)) Then
                        .Add x(c), 1
                    ElseIf NCOUNT Then
                        .Item(x(c)) = .Item(x(c)) + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    If .Count > 0 Then UNIQUECOUNTIF = Application.Sum(.items)
End With
End Function
```