# How to avoid references in VBA (Early Binding vs. Late Binding)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, vba

I found a [VBA macro](http://portal.infiniwiz.com/knowledgebase/37/Setup-Outlook-to-print-attachments-of-incoming-emails-automatically.html) that prints Outlook attachments automatically. A rule triggers the macro.

But the macro needs a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to work. I saved the code in *ThisOutlookSession* and it works fine when I reference the library via *Tools » References.*

But the reference needs to be added every time the program is opened. The macro is there after the startup, but the reference is not. I would like the macro to run continuously without the need for any additional clicks upon system startup.

```
Sub LSPrint(Item As Outlook.MailItem)  
    On Error GoTo OError

    'detect Temp
    Dim oFS As FileSystemObject
    Dim sTempFolder As String
    Set oFS = New FileSystemObject
    'Temporary Folder Path
    sTempFolder = oFS.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)

    'creates a special temp folder
    cTmpFld = sTempFolder & "\OETMP" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss")
    MkDir (cTmpFld)

    'save & print
    Dim oAtt As Attachment
    For Each oAtt In Item.Attachments
      FileName = oAtt.FileName
      FullFile = cTmpFld & "\" & FileName

      'save attachment
      oAtt.SaveAsFile (FullFile)

      'prints attachment
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(0)
      Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(FullFile)
      objFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")

    Next oAtt

    'Cleanup
    If Not oFS Is Nothing Then Set oFS = Nothing
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then Set objFolder = Nothing
    If Not objFolderItem Is Nothing Then Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    If Not objShell Is Nothing Then Set objShell = Nothing

  OError:
    If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
      Err.Clear
    End If
    Exit Sub

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please have a look at ["VBA Early Binding" and "VBA Late Binding".](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/interdev/earlyvslatebinding.htm) for advantages and disadvantages of both methods.

You are using Earling Binding in this line: `Set oFS = New FileSystemObject`.  "New" is a good indicator that Early binding is used.  That's why you have to enable a reference on every machine where the macro runs.

If you use Late Binding, you don't have to enable references. The macro would work on every machine.

[image]

You can convert Early Binding

```
Dim oFS  As FileSystemObject 
Set oFS = New FileSystemObject
```

to Late Binding

```
Dim oFS  As Object 
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

**Attention:** If you use Late Binding, underlying numerical values of named variables are unknown to the system. You have to convert those named variables to their corresponding numerical value.

To get the numerical value, temporarily re-enable your library (e.g. *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*), go to the VBA editor and open the immediate window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Write for example `?TemporaryFolder` into the immediate window and press enter.  As you see in the screenshot `2` is the value of our named variable `TemporaryFolder`

[image]

Repeat the steps for all other problematic variables and replace them with their value. Finally untick the library reference and your code is running on every machine whether the library is enabled or not.

```
oFS.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)   'with Early Binding
oFS.GetSpecialFolder(2)                 'with Late Binding
```

Comment: I'm getting a "75 - Path/File access error" after replacing the lines...

Comment: The program stops after I press F8 with " MkDir (cTmpFld)" highlighted

Comment: My fault, I missed that named variable `TemporaryFolder`. See my edit for an explanation.

Comment: Will that numerical value be the same each time I run the macro? It's important for the macro to work wach time without midifications.

Comment: Yes, it will be.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now after startup (before running the macro), the box "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" is ticked. Is this what should happen?

Answer (score 7):

It is good to know, that

- Early Binding ( Explicitly checked Reference links ) is useful for the development or debugging, because of VBA editor Intellisense, strong object type control and named constants. It is also reportedly faster.
- Late Binding ( independent on Reference links) is useful for inter-machine compatibility.

I use with advantage the fast switching of Early/Late binding.

- I set by the VBA Editor in the VBA Project properties the Conditional compilation arguments to  `EarlyBinding = 1`.

[image: VBA Project properties]

- I use then for the development the conditional compilation directives like below, with active EarlyBinding branch.
- When ready to release, I switch to `EarlyBinding = 0` and the project turns From Early to Late Binding for the final Late binding testing.
- Edit: Do not forget to cancel the References previously explicitly used for the Early Binding

For the FileSystemObject TemporaryFolder example, it can be illustrated as:

```
Sub EarlyVsLateBindingtest()

#If Earlybinding Then
   Dim oFS As Scripting.FileSystemObject
   Set oFS = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
#Else
   Const TemporaryFolder = 2
   Dim oFS As Object
   Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
#End If

oFS.GetSpecialFolder (TemporaryFolder)

End Sub
```

Comment: In that case, don't be shy ... MORE, please.  ;-)